# In Scrum, why don't you use aging and guaranteed time slice to prevent outdated tasks in the backlog?

Tags: agile, scrum, backlog

If there are many tasks in the backlog and the product owner keeps adding them, some of the tasks become outdated and in practice they are never implemented by the team. Why don't we borrow some techniques that are used in thread scheduling to prevent thread starvation like:

- **aging** – task's priority could be automatically increased over time
- **guaranteed time slice** – it could be guaranteed that in the next 10 sprints a task is taken into the sprint for at least 1 sprint.

It could prevent the tasks from being outdated like operating system prevents threads from being starved.

Comment: "the product owner keeps adding [tasks]" This is your underlying problem.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: no, it's not, Quite the opposite.

Comment: And voters, remember, downvotes are for bad questions, not for bad ideas.

Comment: For the purpose of the question, it might be good to consider _cui bono_, i.e. who stands to gain from executing said task? Because most systems are set up in a way that pressure only comes from those who benefit from the work being done (hence why a PO will usually not push for a technical debt task to be handled)

Comment: You are assuming that every task *should* be done. That's absolutely not the case. However if by "taken into the sprint" as in "we will spend a reasonable effort to evaluate if the task is obsolete or not and if not if it makes sense to be done or not" then you might have something that could work, although you still will not have any guarantee, you'll just end up with a slightly cleaner backlog with periodically evaluated tasks... but this still takes some time from actual development work so it's not free

Comment: There's a fundamental theorem in queuing theory: If you put things into a queue faster than they come out, the length of the queue approaches infinity, and so does the average amount of time that things have to wait in the queue. Many engineers who don't know anything about queuing theory and don't think queuing theory applies to their problem find themselves trying to disprove this without realizing it. Not that I'm a queuing theorist either, but I think it's very funny that such an obvious thing is missed so often.

Comment: @PhilipKendall If the PO doesn't keep adding tasks, the devs will eventually find themselves out of a job.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is no issue with collecting new feature ideas for a product in the product backlog, even if those ideas will not be implemented within the next five years. Not every idea for a feature is worth the effort to be implemented now, still it might be worth to collect the ideas for keeping up a strategic development plan and evaluate older ideas from time to time.

However, the situation that some of the feature ideas are demanded by a lot of users or stakeholders regularly, maybe in different variations, can be more easily detected by bookkeeping those ideas in the backlog. We can add a remark to the item, telling who has already asked for the feature, when, and  - not to forget - for what purpose(!). This can be an indicator for giving this backlog item a higher priority and pull it into one of the next sprints.

When some of the tasks *really* "become outdated", as you wrote, in the sense that they became obsolete, one can consider to delete them (and not to give them an even higher priority, obviously). Maybe the code base has evolved up to a point where the task makes no sense any more, maybe the feature is covered by some other features which are already implemented, maybe the feature idea itself has become obsolete because the use case does has lost importance for the users or can be solved differently by some 3rd party software. If the product owners detect such items, they should either remove, archive, or rewrite them.

Let me disclose that I am not talking about theory. What I wrote above is part of my daily work. One of the product backlogs I maintain is more than twenty years old (we actually never called it "product backlog", the approach of keeping such log items is quite independent from Scrum and applies to almost any long-term product development, regardless of the methodology). This backlog contains more than 200 open feature ideas which might be implemented at some day in the future. Still we would never priorize them "by age", that would definitely make no sense.

Comment: Although I agree with this, there are people who will have an "issue with collecting new feature ideas for a product in the product backlog". See the #NoBacklogs movement. There are plenty of arguments made by proponents, but none that I consider to be strong or convincing.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: thanks for the keyword, didn't know this, I looked it up. Those people surely have a point. If one maintains a backlog for a long-living product the way I scetched it, one surely has to care for who gets to see it and that it is not misinterpreted. Though the backlog contains several customers ideas, I usually don't show it to customers. Instead , I have a high level document with the mentioned strategic development plan  at hand, focussing on the planned things for the next 6 to 12 months. This is also what we use in the team.

Comment: Yeah. They have some interesting ideas. And having a very large backlog is definitely wasteful. And maybe this is my background in regulated industries, but we need to maintain a known issues list of reported bugs, including those that are so much of an edge case we won't fix them. That's a backlog. I do think you need to clean it up and be able to show the right things to the right stakeholders, but the #NoBacklogs movement made more sense before the widespread use of electronic tooling with searching and filtering capabilities.

Answer (score 33):

Why should a task become ever more important just because it's old? The point of agile methods is to decide what to do based on *current* info, not on outdated info. If you do it properly, then a task that keeps getting not pulled cannot be the most important task.

Comment: This. If anything it should be considered if you need to keep the task at all -> if it actually had any priority, you would feel the pressure from the stakeholders to go about implementing. Furthermore, this is a sign of bad backlog and sprint - you should actually aim for your sprint load to match the actual team capacity / velocity (these days usually inferred indirectly through comparing with previous sprint deliveries). Whoever is managing the backlog should actually take care not to have the "aging" items in the backlog.

Comment: Tasks may become more important to resolve as they age not "just because they are old", but for example because someone may have been waiting an increasingly long time without a resolution. It's often not reasonable to keep people waiting indefinitely, and the labour cost of constantly reviewing old tasks to an appropriate level of detail, including communicating with the originator(s), may well exceed the cost of simply getting on with tasks. Originators are also unlikely to be pleased if their requests are treated purely as "fire and forget", rather than something they can rely on.

Comment: @Steve: If the originator is annoyed at the task not getting completed, and they're not footing the bill as a stakeholder, there's an easy option - they foot the bill for another developer to take time on their preferred feature request. If enough stakeholders are and product owners are happy with the current result, then it may be that the task was achieved through a different ticket because the implementation of how that idea should be done may have changed during intermediate builds, and better ways were devised. That is what "The point of agile methods is based on current info." means.

Comment: @Steve that should be brought up by the stakeholder. "What happened with the resolution to X?" would be a reason to increase the priority. There is no way to guess whether they care that much or not. For example, maybe a user notices a missing comma in a notification that's not shown for another three months. does that mean that in two months time this typo is more important than it was before? No, because the user hasn't even encountered it again yet.

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st, the point is that developers aren't the only staff in a company who have priorities or need things to be done. Unless you have explicitly agreed that a specific task is best-effort, fire-and-forget, with no timeframe for completion, then in general it isn't reasonable to keep originators waiting indefinitely. I don't think an "agile method" means accumulating endless task lists with potentially no finality on any requests. The progress of requests usually needs to be coordinated with the originator periodically. You wouldn't accumulate them endlessly.

Comment: @VLAZ, what that sounds like to me is that you're rationing your service by how much other staff are willing to spend their valuable time and attention pestering you to get things done. A missing comma in a dialog box sounds to me like something that could and should lead to the source code being fixed on the spot in most circumstances - tracking it as an explicit request and an explicit piece of work would be a massive overhead compared to simply editing the code.

Comment: @Steve why would the PO be editing the code? Or why would the developers be the ones gathering the requirements? A simple typo fix would still cost at least 30 minutes of work, if not more. If it's high priority for the end-users - sure, that time can be spent there. Or it can be spent on something the user thinks is more important. It's down to priorities.

Comment: Have to agree with Steve here: if adding a missing comma takes half a work-hour, then whatever you're doing, it's *not* Agile.

Comment: @KilianFoth do you not count the code review, testing, and other administrative time around this? If you want to only count how long it takes for a single person to find and change some text, then sure, it's less. If you count the time from starting a task to it being completed, then that's a lot more than adding a comma.

Comment: Adding a comma shouldn't need dedicated code review, testing and admin. Either push it out without any of those checks because it's small enough that a mistake is unlikely, or wrap it up in a bundle with other changes and have them all reviewed tested etc together.

Comment: @bdsl I suggest we stop discussing the specifics about my example and instead focus on what the example is *about*  - a non-critical change that nevertheless takes some time. So far, the only discussion has been scrutiny of the specifics and suggestions how it should be handled, rather than using an example as the example it's meant to serve as. So, please everyone - if you want to comment on how commas should be handled in the code - don't.

Comment: @VLAZ, sorry I wrote the comments above without seeing your last. Let's forget about commas then. My point was this: people who make requests generally either expect them to be done on some reasonable timeframe (that gives the executor of the work some flexibility on how to schedule their own work and cope with priorities), or they expect to be told that there is no reasonable hope of the request being done and they should seek to cope permanently in a different way - or try again next year. It's not usually reasonable to expect people to put things on an endless list with no finality.

Comment: @Steve Users should still be the final arbiters of what they want. Not time. I can't imagine a user being delighted being told "we implemented these 10 minor things that you reported ages ago. Rather than the business critical feature you told us about a couple of week ago". Users' priorities can change, I doubt they all wait with bated breath for every single minor thing. In fact, I know for a fact they don't. They are usually happier receiving business critical functionality (something that saves them hours a day), instead of minor and easily overlooked cosmetic improvements.

Comment: @Steve if a user does feel something relatively small is a priority, then by all means, that's what *they* should communicate. More than once I've seen clients been *asked* "But what about X which was reported months ago, are you still interested" and they'd say "no" for a vast variety of reasons. Some times it just loses priority, or just loses relevance (e.g., functionality that is going to be changed/removed), or it was reported by a previous employee and the current one has different opinion. Etc.

Comment: @VLAZ, all I'm suggesting is that the age of a request is something that should contribute towards its priority for *resolution*. That resolution may be to cancel the request.

Comment: @Steve: The core issue is that the development team has a budget - time or monetary wise - to tackle the wide range of requests from stakeholders. Some of the stakeholders are internal to the developer's company, and they would be able to directly take from their budget in terms of costs towards paying for more hours, overtime, another developer, or even their team members, etc., towards making sure the ticket is completed in an upcoming sprint. Depending on where the team is in the development cycle, other things might be way more higher priority and other tasks have a consequence for missing

Comment: (As for situations that seem small like "Add a comma" might end up ballooning - if there's one typo, there's likely another, that should probably be fixed at the same time. And if these commas are in the Terms of Service or in a EULA, that might be something where the Project Owner pushes back and says "Please, legal, review this change in the context of the entire document, and just list all changes needed as one ticket, if necessary.".)

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st, these are fair points but I'm not sure how it bears on the issue of whether old tasks on a list should be prioritised for resolution (that is, prioritised for some kind of action that will lead to those tasks ceasing to be on the list any longer, which could either be by successful execution or by cancellation).

Comment: @Steve: Primarily on the budget concern - priority is used to assign tasks for a given sprint, but resolving old tickets as being outdated or putting them into an upcoming sprint is something outside the scope of a sprint, usually; most of the time, it'd be brought up, and then after review, immediately lowered in priority, because more current tasks are higher priority for the Project Owner, the Stakeholders, and/or the Developers.,

Comment: @Steve: Perhaps another way of thinking about it - The aging -> increased priority approach works about as well as creating all 50 of your tickets with them listed as maximum urgency priority.

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st, a question then is, what process do you have to ensure that (a) the volume of open requests is *controlled* to match what your resources (current or foreseeable) can reasonably cope with, and (b) to recover from a situation where poor control or unexpected change means the volume is no longer matched? I can understand that if your task list is run like a "suggestion box", then there isn't necessarily any reason to control the volume, but my experience of development is that many (if not all) requests must be treated as something more accountable than mere suggestions.

Comment: @Steve Are you saying the list of open requests shouldn't ever grow?

Comment: @Steve: In my experience, if it gets to the point of being added to a sprint, *that* is when it's treated requests are treated as more than suggestions - when it comes to bug reports, usually a notification is sent to the project owner,and if they consider it urgent, they'll bring it up in a communication method with the developers to be assigned to it. If it isn't obviously urgent,it likely ends up in a Triage Meeting, to determine if it *is* something that can be worked on and still meet the sprint deadlines, or if it can be delayed to an upcoming sprint. Outside that,escalation needs budget

Comment: @nasch, not without limit, no. Even if it is a suggestion box where you don't have to coordinate with anybody and no guarantees have been offered to anybody, you'd still drown in information yourself if you allowed limitless accumulation. Forgetting the right things (and controlling the recording of things in the first place), is as important as remembering the right things, in order to control the effort necessary for collecting, organising, and usefully analysing the information you have.

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st, there may be a difference in context. I'm just unclear how you get staff to use their valuable time sitting down to describe the development they want and describe their circumstances in a way that allows you to continually judge and re-judge the relative value and priority of their request amongst dozens (or hundreds?) of others, without any implied likelihood that you're actually going to execute their request? I would suspect this apparently preliminary process would actually form a significant part of the sunk cost of developing a particular request.

Answer (score 8):

Who says that you can't? Just because the practices aren't prescribed by Scrum doesn't mean that the Product Manager can't implement them. In fact, the Scrum Guide even says that you can add to it:

> Scrum exists only in its entirety and functions well as a container for other techniques, methodologies, and practices.

There's also the argument that having too much work in the Product Backlog hampers the transparency and understanding of it, so unnecessary work should be removed, and there are indeed many ways or criteria to remove something from the Product Backlog.

Today, electronic tooling to manage the Product Backlog means that you don't need to necessarily discard or "throw out" anything - you can use filtering to keep the team and stakeholders focused on the most important work while still keeping track of older, less relevant ideas and having a way to find them (and perhaps any decisions made about them) if you need to in the future.

Answer (score 4):

I actually use almost the *opposite* approach. I maintain a tiered priority backlog: `A` has 2 items, `B` has 4 items, `C` has 16 items and `D` has 64 items, and then the idea graveyard.

Adding an item to the list defaults to adding it to `D` and the oldest-since-last-touched item goes into the idea graveyard. Items can bubble up in priority by swapping with an item from the next highest section, again by default it is the oldest-since-last-touched that gets deprioritized.

The main idea here (besides clear priorities) is that new ideas are shiny and exciting, but bubbling them up into higher priority requires those tough questions *about* priority and timing. After a while the shininess wears off and those that people really want to keep on the list are "touched" to keep them there. (See also [*Bets, not Backlogs*](https://basecamp.com/shapeup/2.1-chapter-07)).

Comment: What happens when items get done? Do the empty spots get auto-filled from the next level, or only with an active decision by which item to promote?

Comment: Today I use an active decision every 2 weeks (before sprint planning).

Answer (score 1):

Empiricism and value. Scrum is an empirical process where we take new knowledge and make decisions based on all that we have learned and use that to find the most valuable items for the team to pull into every sprint. Just because it has a long lead time does not increase the value, in fact, often as time goes on it becomes obsolete. We never want to guarantee an item's  delivery date because we don't know the order of future valuable items.  New items may become more important for the team to work on

Answer (score 1):

Is an old task automatically outdated?  In the feature-enhancement queue for some software I'm working on is a request to change the workflow for a task to require one click rather than four.  It's been in the queue for more than twenty years now, and is still as relevant as the day it was entered.

Is an old task automatically worth working on?  The task in question isn't performed very often, and it's questionable if the time lost from the inefficient workflow has yet exceeded the time needed to implement the change.

Thread scheduling is based around the assumption that every queued task is worth working on.  That's not true for software development.

Comment: it's not an answers, you only add more questions and make it less clear